# Traer y mostrar datos json con ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

tengo un select en un formulario, y quiero que al seleccionar un option, me muestre los relacionados a este en unos input text en el formulario (para despues enviarlo y guardar en BD).. 
Use un ajax para enviar el valor seleccionado y hacer la consulta a BD correspondiente, pero al traer el resultado, no me muestra nada y me tira el mensaje de "error" de la funcion..
soy bastante novato en todo esto.. Gracias de antemano.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function objetoAjax(){
        var xmlhttp=false;
        try {
               xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
               try {
                  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
               } catch (E) {
                       xmlhttp = false;
               }
        }
 
        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
               xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        }

        return xmlhttp;

}


function mifuncion(valor){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'buscard.php',
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'JSON',
            data : {valor:valor},
         
         success : function(json) {


        $("#precio").value = json.precio;
        $("#moneda").value = json.moneda;
            },
 
// código a ejecutar si la petición falla;
            error : function(xhr, status) {
                alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
            }
});
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s6">
 
 <select id="propiedad" name="propiedad" class="browser-default" onchange="mifuncion(this.value)">
                            
                            <option value="nulo" selected="">Propiedad</option>
                            <?PHP
                            $sql= ("SELECT * FROM propiedades");
                            $res= mysql_query ($sql,$cnx);
                            while ($array= mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {


                            echo "<option value=".$array['Id'].">".$array['Titulo']."</option>";

                            }
echo '
</select>
</div>
</br>';

?>


Precio: <input id="precio" type="text" name="precio" class="validate" aria-required="true" required> </br>

Moneda: <input id="moneda" type="text" name="moneda" class="validate" aria-required="true" required> </br>
```

buscard.php

```html
<?PHP
require_once ("inc/html.head.php");
?>
<?php
if ( !function_exists('json_decode') ){
    function json_decode($content, $assoc=false){
                require_once 'Services/JSON.php';
                if ( $assoc ){
                    $json = new Services_JSON(SERVICES_JSON_LOOSE_TYPE);
        } else {
                    $json = new Services_JSON;
                }
        return $json->decode($content);
    }
}

if ( !function_exists('json_encode') ){
    function json_encode($content){
                require_once 'Services/JSON.php';
                $json = new Services_JSON;
               
        return $json->encode($content);
    }
}
?>
<?php

//el dato que enviamos a traves de ajax
$valor=$_GET['valor'];
 
//la consulta que necesites para trer el codigo y el nombre del cliente
$query=("SELECT * FROM propiedades WHERE Id =".$valor);
 
$r=mysql_query($query,$cnx);
while($resultados= mysql_fetch_array($r)){

 
$precio=$resultados['Precio'];
$moneda=$resultados['Moneda'];

//esta variable es para retornar los datos
$jsondata = array();
 
//agregamos nuestros datos al array para retornarlos
$jsondata['precio'] = $precio;
$jsondata['moneda'] = $moneda;

}
//este header es para el retorno correcto de datos con json
//header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
 echo json_encode($jsondata);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

La verdad es que lo que subes esta bastante enredado y me costo un poco entender lo que subes, te escribiré un ejemplo en como se puede hacer un llamado con ajax  y luego enviar por post para guardar lo seleccionado espero te quede mas claro (voy a obviar el uso de librearias como jquery para el uso de ajax)

Html

```
<div>
 <select id="propiedad" name="propiedad" class="browser-default">
  <option>tus dato de la consulta</option>
 </select>

 Precio: <input id="precio" type="text" name="precio" class="validate" aria-required="true" required> </br>

 Moneda: <input id="moneda" type="text" name="moneda" class="validate" aria-required="true" required> </br>
</div>
```

js para uso de ajax

```
$('#propiedad').change(function () {

var propiedad = $('#propiedad').val();

var consulta = $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: ('buscar.php'),
    data: {valor: valor},
    dataType: 'JSON'
});

consulta.done(function (data) {
    if (data.error !== undefined) {
        $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: ' + data.error);
        return false;
    } else {
        if (data.NombreApellido !== undefined) {
            $('#Datoscilindro #txtNombreApell').val(data.NombreApellido);
            $('#txtNombreApell').attr('readonly', 'true');
        }
        return true;
    }
});
consulta.fail(function () {
    $('#estado').html('Ha habido un error contactando el servido de clientesr.');
    return false;
});
```

})

buscado.php

```
 $conexion = new \mysqli(tus datos de conexion);
if($conexion->connect_error){echo "Fallo al conectar:".$conexion->connect_error() or die();} if( !empty($_POST['valor'])){
    $id = $_POST['valor'];
    $sql = "SELECT* FROM tabla  WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = $conexion->query($sql);
    die(json_encode($result->fetch_array()));
}
$conexion->close();
```

esto es una forma sencilla de hacerlo, hay mas maneras y mejores practicas para hacerlo refactorizando el codigo pero como recien estas empezando es una buen punto de inicio

espero te sirva

Comment: Hola Pablo, muchas gracias por responder. Lo que intento hacer es traer dos datos de la consulta (precio, moneda).. la libreria que uso es <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ahora modifique mi codigo como lo que me mandaste, salvo en la parte de ajax donde dice {valor : valor} le puse {valor : propiedad}, y sigue sin funcionar (dice "Ha habido un error contactando el servido de clientesr"), es mas, ahora cuando consulto los valores que consulta me muestra {"precio":null,"moneda":null}, cuando antes si me mostraba los valores reales. (No se si eso tendrá que ver con el type POST)..
Tambien me gustaria poder aclararte la parte del codigo que esta enredada para que lo puedas entender con mas claridad (la verdad que si soy bastante desprolijo jaja). Muchas gracias.

Comment: Al cambiar por type :GET, sigue sin mostrar nada, pero no me tira ningun mensaje de error tampoco..
Hace mucho que estoy renegando con este problema, la verdad que si hubiese otra manera de lograr el resultado tambien seria bienvenida..

Comment: Estimado en mi ejemplo estoy setiando unos campos que yo estaba usando, En tu caso debiese ser asi       consulta.done(function (data) {
    if (data.error !== undefined) {
        $('#estado').html('Ha ocurrido un error: ' + data.error);
        return false;
    } else {
        if (data.precio!== undefined) {
            $('#iddetudiv #precio').val(data.nombredetucolumna);
        }
        return true;
    }
});

Comment: para poder ver el problema del ajax en tu navegador abre la consola de desarrollador y ve la pestaña network ahi se veran todas las peticiones ajax y al hacerle doble click abrira una pestaña en el buscador en tu buscador.php has un var_dump(tuvariable) para ver que estas recibiendo, de igual manera a tu select para depurar tu codigo y encontrar el error

Comment: Pablo, sisi, tenia el codigo asi como decis, y sigue sin funcionar. 
Ahora puse var_dump($jsondata) al final de buscard.php, lo que no se es en que parte del select colocar el otro var_dump..

Comment: Y en cuanto a la consola, la abri pero sinceramente no sabria leerla adecuadamente me parece..

Comment: @jorgelaquis el var_dump colocalo debajo de la variable que recibe el valor en buscador.php lo de la consola debes abrirla e ir a la pestaña network, intentalo si sigue sin funcionar cuentame

Comment: Pablo, con el var_dump($valor) en buscard.php me muestra string(2) "24" {"precio":"12132","moneda":"Dolares"} .. 
En Network de mi pagina principal donde esta la funcion me muestra : Request URL: http://localhost:90/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min1576.js?ver=1.2.1 Status: 404 Not Found.

Comment: si te muestra error 404 es porque la ruta no esta bien puesta y por lo tanto no esta encontrando, corrige eso para que no de problema 404 puede ser eso porque no te trae la info

Comment: Pablo, en el caso de http://localhost:90/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min1576.js?ver=1.2.1 , la verdad no sabria decirte de donde viene esa URL, no es ninguna carpeta de las que tengo en el www.. no sabria que corregir.